# iScroll not responding at all inside div with transition

Tags: javascript, css, iscroll

I have a an app that I will port to Phonegap, and I am using iScroll 5 to handle some aspects of the scrolling.

This app is built with some CSS from [Ratchet](http://maker.github.io/ratchet/), but quite modified, and just about all the Ratchet javascript has been removed; also jQuery; FastClick.js.

The app is a single HTML file (not using `push.js` from Ratchet), and divided into `Pages` that are inside a master `Content` area, and change with CSS3 transitions.  So far, `iScroll` is used in two places; initialized at the same time with two different calls to `IScroll("#id")`.

The first `iScroll` works fine - it is just a simple set of sections with paragraphs scrolling between two fixed header/footer bar elements.

The second one wraps an entire page that shows on an internal transition.  In other words, its not a page as described above, but it is a full width element that is taller than the page, and sits beneath the header and one other button set.  That may or may not be important, but when it shows the first time, there is nothing anywhere I can do to get it to initialize properly.

Since the js variable is global, I can see it, and this is what I have noted so far:

```
> myScroll.initiated=0

> myScroll.enabled=true

> myScroll.scrollBy and myScroll.scrollTo both work as expected

> myScroll.refresh() and myScroll.resetPosition called from 
  js file or from console have no effect whatsoever
```

I am using Chrome with touch events enabled for development, but the behavior is replicated on my iPhone. The div (which only contains a simple list) responds to `touchmove` events, in that they are logged in the console, but there is literally no scrolling movement at all.  I believe that there is probably a bug related to multiple layers being positioned with transitions, but I don't know what to do next.

Can anyone offer some guidance on,

1. How To Fix This
2. Or failing that, what is the best placed to look to debug this, and find out why nothing is happening.

Thanks